# POST in java is different from that in android?

Tags: java, android, post, tcp

though the code is a little long, most of them are very simple IMO. now im writing an android app that posts data to a website and displays the returned HTML code to the TextView.First i wrote a simple java POST method, it works perfect in my computer(on linux, post username and password to `http://forum.xda-developers.com/login.php`, and it returned the HTML successfully, though which prompts me that the username and password is incorrect):

```
package com.app.main;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Connection
{
    String returnText = "";                        
    String returnLine;

            //data which is about to be posted
    public String data = "vb_login_username=test&vb_login_password&securitytoken=guest&do=login";

    public String returnHTML()
    {
    try {
            URL url = new URL("http://forum.xda-developers.com/login.php");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            while((returnLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                returnText += returnLine;
            }

            wr.close();
            rd.close();

            return returnText;

    } catch (Exception e) {
         return "ERROR: "+e.getMessage();
      }
    }
}
```

i tested the code using:

```
Connection net_start = new Connection();
System.out.println(net_start.returnHTML());
```

perfect. HTML returned successfully, then i go to write an android app, which is very simple, only having a button and an TextView on it. when i press the button, the TextView will display the returned HTML if successfully. Here is the source code of the main Activity.java

```
package com.app.main;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView displayResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayResult);
    Button login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

    //set dispalyResult scrollable
    displayResult.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Connection net_start = new Connection();
            displayResult.setText(net_start.returnHTML());      

        }

    });

    }

}
```

very simple code, the only difference from that above is that i set the returned HTML display on the TextView instead of the command line. but i failed. According to debugging, i found the app throws an Exception at that line in Connection.java: `OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());`, the catched e said that: `java.net.UnknownHostException: forum.xda-developers.com`, but i indeed can login the xda-developers website on my cellphone(i debug the app using `adb` on my phone), what's the matter with that? cannot android use `URLConnection`? any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it available?

```
 <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your **android application's manifest** file..

Your code works fine in my case:

The result of `returnText` is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en"><head><meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" ><meta name="keywords" content="XDA,MDA,Vario,HTC,Qtek,wallaby,wizard,tytn,hermes,alpine,prophet,i-mate,jam,dopod,tornado,typhoon,programming,coding,modding,wiki,forum,news,xdatools,xdaunlock,romkitchen,rom,development,lobster,unlock,imei" /><meta name="description" content="Android and Windows Mobile Developers - The Largest Community for Smartphone Hacks and Development of Apps" /><style type="text/css" id="vbulletin_css">/*** vBulletin 3.8.7 CSS* Style: 'XDA 2010'; Style ID: 16*/@import url("http://media.xda-developers.com/clientscript/vbulletin_css/style-e9bec9ef-00016.css");
```

Comment: thx a million! its `uses-permission`! add that line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`, then it also works perfect on my android phone!